# Complete function that convertTemplate() which takes rest parameters as input and returns a concatenated string

Tags: javascript

Problem Statement: Complete function that `convertTemplate()` which takes rest parameters as input and returns a concatenated string as input irrespective of the 
data type passed as an argument to the function.

```
sample input: convertTemplate('aa',3)
output : aa3
```

The output is right but on an online competitive site is saying that something is missing according to the Problem Statement.

Here is my snippet:

```js
let convertTemplate = (...input) => {
    var count = 1;
    for (var x = 1; x < input.length; x++) {
        if (count === 1) {
            var firstInput = input[0];
            count++;
        }
        //console.log(firstInput)
        var firstInput = firstInput + input[x];
    }
    console.log(firstInput);
};
convertTemplate('ae', 2, 'aadadd', 3);
```

Comment: If single argument is allowed, then you algorithm will return `undefined`.

Comment: try to use `return` at the end of the function instead of `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

The "Problem Statement" says to use [rest parameters](https://javascript.info/rest-parameters-spread-operator).

Like so:

```js
let convertTemplate = (...input) => {
  return input.reduce((previous, current) => {
    return previous + current;
  });
};
console.log(convertTemplate('ae', 2, 'aadadd', 3));
```

Comment: It's probably some sort of markup. Try adding `'use strict';` at the top.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood the question, but if you only want to join the parameters:

```js
let convertTemplate = (...input) => input.join('');
console.log(convertTemplate('ae', 2, 'aadadd', 3));
```

Comment: I have tried this also but still, it says something's missing that's why I used a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Code is for Edwisor Students!

Problem Statement: 
Complete function that convertTemplate() which takes rest parameters as input 
and returns a concatenated string as input irrespective of the 
data type passed as arguments to the function.

sample input - convertTemplate('aa',3)
output : aa3
Soution:

```js
let convertTemplate = (...input)=>
{  
  let abc="";
   let bc = input.join();
   let count=0;
      for(var i=0;i<bc.length;i++)
      {
          let y=bc.charAt(i);
              console.log(y);
          console.log("i'm here"+ i);
           if(bc[i]==',')
          {
            count++;
          }
          else{

            abc+=bc[i];
          }
      }

   return abc;

};
console.log(convertTemplate("av",32));
```

I used the last line of code so that I could check the code in Codepen
FYI: the count variable is not used and I left it like that.